# Move files into subdirectories based on prefix combinations

Tags: bash, wildcard, subdirectory

I have a directory with very large number of files following this pattern:

filtered.{x}.R1.clean.id_{y}.{z}

x and y are wildcards, z is file format.

I hope to move the files into subdirectories with X_Y based on their x and y combinations

thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Please add the tag for the shell you want to use and remove the `shell` tag. See the description of that tag for further info. BTW: You're also not describing a problem, just a task for which you want a solution. SO doesn't work like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```bash
#!/bin/bash

while IFS='/' read -r x y
do
    d=${x}_$y
    mkdir -p "$d"
    mv filtered."$x".R1.clean.id_"$y".* "$d/"
done < <(
    printf '%s\n' filtered.*.R1.clean.id_*.* |
    sed -nE 's/^filtered\.([^.]+)\.R1\.clean\.id_([^.]+)\..+$/\1\/\2/p' |
    sort -u
)
```

The idea is to first get all the existing `x` `y` then move the matching files.

**remark:** I'm not sure that it makes much sense to create those directories, unless there is a **lot** of `z` for each `x y` pair.

Comment: Thank you! I have tried but I got: -bash: syntax error near unexpected token `$'<(\n    printf \'%s\\n\' filtered.*.R1.clean.id_*.* |\n    sed -nE \'s/^filtered\\.(.+)\\.R1\\.clean\\.id_(.+)\\..+$/\\1\\/\\2/p\' |\n    sort -u\n)'', what does this mean? many thanks again!

Comment: Thank you! It solved partially the problem, I have these errors now: mv: cannot stat 'filtered.341.R1.clean.id_CGCTGATC.fq.*': No such file or directory
mv: cannot stat 'filtered.341.R1.clean.id_CGCTGATC.fq.bam.*': No such file or directory
mv: cannot stat 'filtered.341.R1.clean.id_CGCTGATC.fqLog.*': No such file or directory
mv: cannot stat 'filtered.341.R1.clean.id_CGCTGATC.fqSJ.out.*': No such file or directory. Which looks end it is not picking up the end in a right way.. some files have {.z} some have {z.z1}....

Comment: I fixed the code for `$y` not to contain any dot but I don't really know what you consider being `$y`